# Strong Predictor in Random Forests

Tags: cart

My statistical learning book asserts that when decision trees are constructed, m out of p predictors are randomly selected for consideration in a split. The idea here apparently is to decorrelate trees obtained in bagging by weakening the effect of a strong predictor.  If we have p predictors to choose from, and at each split we can only use m predictors, they say on average, (p - m)/p of the splits will involve the strong predictor.  Why?

Answer (score 3):

There might be a typo there.

The concept that I think the text should be trying to emphasize is that random forests are robust to noise variables. Thus if you have $100$ noise variables and $2$ relevant variables you should still get good answers. Where $r$ is number of relevant variables, the chance of selecting a relevant variable will be:
$$
1 - \bigg(\frac{C(p-r,\ m)}{C(p,\ m)}\bigg)
$$
This is not a linear function and relatively robust to small $r/p$.  If $r=1$, then:
$$
1-\frac{p-m}p
$$
I hope that makes sense / is right. Bit rushed so didn't check the maths that closely.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user34658. I took the liberty of marking up your post with $\LaTeX$ for easier readability. Please make sure it still says what you want it to.